# How to ensure minimum value during both creation and deletion in mongodb?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

Consider:

1. `Summary` schema with a `minimum_score` property
2. `PersonRecord` schema with a `score` property
3. A single `Summary` document should contain `minimum_score` of all the `PersonRecord` documents.

Following two actions are done in a transaction:

1. Insertion of new document in `PersonRecord` collection
2. Update `Summary` document's `minimum_score` property using `{ $min: personRecord.score }`

However, there is another requirement to allow a person to delete his `PersonRecord` document. So consider the scenarios such as following:

1. All of the persons delete their `PersonRecord` documents
2. One person deletes his `PersonRecord` document while another person is inserting a new one.

How can we handle the scenarios in mongodb (mongoose) if we ALWAYS want to have the correct `minimum_score` value in `Summary` document?

I can think of achieve this is using the principle of eventual consistency. Is there any other way?

Comment: Support a person's score is minimum and stored in summary. After that, person just delete his document. So, will summany's minimum_score also be changed?  or, should contain the deleted person's minimum score?

Comment: @mubin986 Summary's minimum_score will be changed/updated according to the remaining PersonRecord documents.

Comment: Why not do this: On each insertion, if the new score is less than the current minimum, update it. On each deletion, if the deleted score is equal to the minimum, iterate over all records to update the minimum.

Comment: There is no problem in handling insertion using $min atomic operation to avoid any concurrency issues.
"if the deleted score is equal to the minimum, iterate over all records to update the minimum. " is not a correct approach